# how to reuse Save and Delete code from repository

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

i want to create an window app using repository pattern... following is my repository code.

model is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Domain.Models
{
   public class Pet
    {
       public int ID { get; set; }


       [Display(Name="Pet Name")]
       public String PetName { get; set; }


       public String Detail { get; set; }


       [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
       public Double Price { get; set; }


       [Display(Name="Pet Code")]
       public int PetCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Interface for model:

```
    using Domain.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


        namespace Domain.Abstract
        {
            public  interface IPetRepository
            {
                IEnumerable<Pet> Pets { get; }
                bool SAvePet(Pet pet);
                Pet DeletePet(int ID);

            }
        }
```

implementation for interface

```
namespace Domain.Concret
{
    public class EFPetRepository:IPetRepository
    {
        public readonly DbAccess context = new DbAccess();

        public IEnumerable<Models.Pet> Pets
        {
            get { return context.Pets ; }
        }

        public bool SAvePet(Models.Pet pet)
        {
            if (pet.ID == 0)
            {
                context.Pets.Add(pet);
            }
            else
            {
                var pt = context.Pets.Find(pet.ID);
                if (pt.ID != null)
                {
                    pt.PetCode = pt.PetCode;
                    pt.PetName = pt.PetName;
                    pt.Price = pt.Price;
                    pt.Detail = pt.Detail;

                }
            }
            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public Models.Pet DeletePet(int ID)
        {
            var pt = context.Pets.Find(ID);
            if (pt != null)
            {
                context.Pets.Remove(pt);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return pt;
        }
    }
}
```

now i want to use it in window form... so how can i reuse its code for save and delete button here:

```
    namespace inventryMangt
{
    public partial class pet : Office2007Form
    {
        private readonly IPetRepository repo;
        public pet()
        {
            repo = new EFPetRepository();

            InitializeComponent();

        }







        private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        repo.SavePet();
        }

        private void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           repo.delete();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is use Generic repository which allow you to initiate object in calling the method.

```
public static void Save<T>(T model) where T : class
{
  // your Context code for saving
}

// call your method
Pet pet = new Pet();
Save<Pet>(pet)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the implementation "EFPetRepository" of the interface IPetRepository in any other project by adding the related namespaces/references. It should be like follows

```
    private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var pet = (Models.Pet)sender;           
       pet.petName= "pet1";
       pet.petCode = "p124";
       repo.SavePet(pet);
    }

    private void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var pet = (Models.Pet)sender;
       repo.delete(pet.ID);
    }
```